# Deploy ASP.NET MVC2 app to IIS6, from a CD, WITHOUT web deploy

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, web-deployment

So I need to deploy an ASP.NET MVC2 web app, developed with VS2010, to IIS6.

The server on which it will be installed does not have Web Deploy installed on it, and while I *do* have administrative privileges on the system, I am not allowed to install the Web Deploy tool (or any other software, for that matter).

Basically, I need to bring my web app deployment package to the server on a CD, and deploy it using nothing but whatever is built in -- the server is running Windows Server 2003, .NET 4.0, IIS 6 and MSSQL Server 2005.  It'd be nice to have the database automatically generated during deployment, but if I need to run a separate SQL script to handle that, it's OK.

I assume this must be possible; but I can't seem to figure out how to do it!

BTW: I know how to configure IIS6 using Wildcard Mapping, etc; the only question here is how to perform the step that would normally be perfomed with the Web Deploy tool (i.e., getting the folder full of web app files deployed into IIS itself.)

Thanks,
-Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a small program to be executed from the CD which simply copies the website image from the CD to the server's website directory.

Comment: I didn't realize you could just copy the website into the server's website directory -- Envision me slapping my forehead right now :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, getting MVC to run on IIS6 requires you to enable Wild card mapping.  I'm assuming this would be doable from a script.